# Tag synonym request: [sso] -> [single-sign-on]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

I noticed that there are two separate tags on Stack Overflow for questions related to Single Sign On, [single-sign-on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/single-sign-on) and [sso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sso).

I believe these are better off as synonyms, and merged.

Comment: Can somebody with enough permissions take a look at this?  I just asked a question in this area and the two tags still exist.

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller: We're on it... I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wow, it's been almost 1 and a half years. Somehow this went unattended for so long despite gathering a considerable amount of votes.

There was yet again [another tiny hiccup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175176/tag-merging-with-synonym-mapping-foo-bar-fails-if-proposal-for-bar-fo) as I was *just* trying to process this, but it's actually finally completed now.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm glad I was able to bump it into your todo list.